# Formula for filter column in Excel

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, multiple-columns

Please suggest a formula for the following requirement:

- One Excel sheet 1 has column A,B,...
  Say, Column A has list of Email Addresses of about 2800+ users
  (Column B has something irrelevant)
  Say, Column C is tilted Date and Column D is titled Status
- Another excel sheet 2 has Column A with email addresses of 100+ users.

My requirement:
In Sheet 1,
I want to filter out the 100+ users in column A and these 100+ users are present in Sheet 2
(I could paste the 100+ users from Sheet 2 to say Column E of Sheet 1
such that only Sheet 1 need to be considered)

So I want to filter 100+ in comparison to column E 100+ names (after copying as above)

Then I can fill in Column C & D after filter.

Note : I don't want to delete rest of the names in Column A, just want to apply filter according to Column E such that only the 100+ names appear in column A so I can fill the corresponding data in Column C & D

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you are after `VLOOKUP()` or `FILTER()` or `XLOOKUP()` or `INDEX()`+`MATCH()` etc etc. You can research and even browse on SO for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

You can whitelist / blacklist values via the COUNTIF function in a filter.

```
=FILTER( range to return, COUNTIF( needle, haystack "range to return"))
```

So if you wanted to create a third sheet and paste those columns as you shown above you could paste this formula in cell A2...

```
=FILTER( 'Sheet 1'!A2:D2801, COUNTIF('Sheet 2'!A2:101, 'Sheet 1'!A2:A2801))
```

And it will auto-populate columns A-D with your desired data. This formula is assuming your 100 desired names are on column A starting on A2. I'm sure you can tweak this a little to fit your needs

Comment: Remember to select my answer as the correct one if it works. Please let me know if you have any questions.